# Expanding Repa array shapes

Tags: haskell, repa

I'm writing a program that generates images, which I would like to bring into a Repa array. I'm currently using the type:

```
data Colour = Colour Double Double Double
```

to represent pixels, and I have a (probably inefficient but functional) function which converts a `Colour` into a `DIM1` array:

```
colourToRepa :: Colour -> Array U DIM1 Double
colourToRepa (Colour r g b) = R.fromListUnboxed (Z :. (3::Int)) [r,g,b]
```

An image in my program at the moment is just a `[Colour]` value with a `(Int, Int)` representing dimensions.

I can use this to build a `Array V DIM2 Colour` easily enough, but is there a way (using `colourToRepa` or otherwise) to expand this array into a `Array U DIM3 Double`?

With lists I could just use `map` but Repa's map preserves the shape of the array (I want to go from a `DIM2` to a `DIM3`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that shapes are stored separately to data in repa, so you would be [reshaping](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.3.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html#g:7) the array from DIM1 to DIM3, without changing the [extent](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.3.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html#g:1) of the array.

We have a DIM1 (flat) array:

```
> let x :: Array DIM1 Double ; x = fromList (Z :. (9::Int)) [1..9]
> x
Array (Z :. 9) [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0]
```

It's extent is:

```
> extent x
Z :. 9
```

Using reshape we can 'cast' the shape of the array from 1D to 3D:

```
> let y :: Array DIM3 Double ;
      y = reshape (Z :. (3::Int) :. (3::Int) :. (1::Int)) x
> y
Array (Z :. 3 :. 3 :. 1) [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0]
```

And its type changes:

```
> :t y
y :: Array DIM3 Double
```

Comment: Ah. I had forgotten that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on precisely how you want to add an extra dimension can also use [extend](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/repa/3.2.3.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Repa.html#v%3aextend), for example:

```
extraDim :: Source a Double =>
            Array a (Z :. Int :. Int) Double ->
            Array D (Z :.Int :. Int :. Int) Double
extraDim a = extend (Any :. i :. All) a
               where (Z :. i :. j) = extent a
```